# Image is not linking

Tags: magento-1.9, html

I have some images on a homepage and everytime I add in a link it does not seem to be working, chances are im typing it wrong or missing something but if you can let me know how to add a link to the image in this code, that would be a great help.

thanks,

```
<div class="homepage-grid-banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid1" style="position:relative;">
                <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/07/big-box-22---.jpg"}}" alt="Visit our showroom" />
                <div class="ribbon theme-border-color" style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;color:#fff;">
                    <div style="position:absolute;right:9%;top:10%;width:90%;text-align:right;">
                        <em style="font-weight:300;font-style:normal;color:#fff;margin-right:26%;">UP TO</em>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:700;color:#fff;">50%</h4>
                        <h5 style="font-weight:600;color:#fff;">OFF</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to simply add an `<a>` for a Link around the image. 
Right now I cannot see any link even in your code.

Try the following

```
<div class="homepage-grid-banner">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="grid1" style="position:relative;">
            <a href="YOUR LINK" title="Your Link title">
                <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/porto/homepage/slider/07/big-box-22---.jpg"}}" alt="Visit our showroom" />
            </a>
                <div class="ribbon theme-border-color" style="position:absolute;right:0;top:0;color:#fff;">
                    <div style="position:absolute;right:9%;top:10%;width:90%;text-align:right;">
                        <em style="font-weight:300;font-style:normal;color:#fff;margin-right:26%;">UP TO</em>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:700;color:#fff;">50%</h4>
                        <h5 style="font-weight:600;color:#fff;">OFF</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

That should be it.